# How to manually delete a cloud build trigger when its missing from the triggers list?

Tags: triggers, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I used to have CloudRun service that would be rebuilt by CloudBuild as soon as something was merged into main of the underlying GitHub repo.

That particular CloudRun service has been long deleted but the trigger still attempts to build it on merge and naturally fails every time.

I tried to figure out how to delete the trigger manually but it is nowhere to be found. It doesn't show up in Github action because its managed by CloudBuild and when I go to CloudBuild -> triggers it is simply not there (regardless of the region)...

Now the whole repo builds are failing because there is this zombie trigger that I cannot kick out and i am also likely being charged for these failed attempts to build something that doesn't exist!
How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Seems like your issue needs to be inspected at project level and in-depth analysis is required to check the route cause. I recommend to contact  [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, it seems that it would cost me 30€ per month to get an answer from GCP support... I think I might just migrate the repo to a different one.